# Create tuple from result of functions in callable variadic tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic

I'm trying to write the following: I have as input a tuple containing N functions. All of those functions can have different return type but only take 1 argument of the same type. I would like to put in a tuple the result of calling each function to a given parameter.

```
template <typename AttributeType, typename ...Functions>
auto f(std::tuple<Functions...> &tupleOfFunctions, const AttributeType &attr)
{
  return std::make_tuple(std::get<0>(tupleOfFunctions)(attr), std::get<1>(tupleOfFunctions)(attr), …, std::get<N>(tupleOfFunctions)(attr));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
template <typename AttributeType, typename ...Functions>
auto f(std::tuple<Functions...> &tupleOfFunctions, const AttributeType &attr)
{
    return std::apply(
        [&](auto &... f) { return std::tuple{f(attr)...}; },
        tupleOfFunctions
    );
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PozuAdI5Mt7eGOwj)

This can be tweaked to handle reference-returning functions transparently as well:

```
template <typename AttributeType, typename ...Functions>
auto f(std::tuple<Functions...> &tupleOfFunctions, const AttributeType &attr)
{
    return std::apply(
        [&](auto &... f) { return std::tuple<decltype(f(attr))...>{f(attr)...}; },
        //                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        tupleOfFunctions
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation in your answer? Why should we use `std::apply`? Thanks.

Comment: @Pierre well, it's just easier. It binds the elements of `tupleOfFunctions` to the `auto &... f` parameter pack, which we can then expand directly. Other solutions are possible, but they need more work to do that same expansion (typically with a helper function and an `std::index_sequence`).

Comment: `std::tuple<decltype(f(attr))...>{f(attr)...}` to handle reference types.

Comment: @Jarod42 I saw your previous comment and had the same thought (since, as I guess you realized, `std::forward_as_tuple` would produce dangling references to expired prvalues). Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Yeah, `std::forward_as_tuple` cannot be used, so I removed that comment for the new one.